# Why reverted commit won't show in new PR?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, pull-request, git-revert

Here's what's happening:

1. created branch XYZ from master
2. committed changes in branch XYZ
3. made PR of XYZ branch to master
4. PR got accepted and code merged into master
5. PR got reverted (it broke stuff)
6. made some commits in branch XYZ in order to fix what commit on item #2 had broken
7. went to Github.com and created new PR, but I only see the last commit and NOT the other commit that was made on item #2

I guess my question is: Why isn't the code committed in item #2 not showing up in my new PR? will the commit that got reverted also be included in this new PR even though I don't see it in the list of changed files?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you push those commits on XYZ to github (to the branch that you are creating the pull request from)?

Comment: @dennisschagt Yes, the commits on XYZ got pushed to master on github, but then reverted as I mentioned. Although I do see the commits in the github master's history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those of you wondering: All I had to do was merge from master to XYZ branch so I could get the latest commits then revert the commit that reverted my code. Then the files in that previously reverted commits showed up in the new PR.

Comment: How did you do the 2nd part? revert the commit that reverted PR

Comment: @ArunGowda something like `git revert -m 1 <commit-SHA>` will revert not only the PR merge commit but all of its children. HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Here goes nothing, but what if you reverted master to before the PR (locally) and push that to master, continue making changes in XYZ and try PR'ing again?

Comment: Thanks! this is an interesting one.. the thing is that the XYZ branch is old, so it doesn't have the newest commits: the PR and the reverted PR. So unless I merge the master on Gihub to the XYZ branch and try that. but it sounds overkill to me. I have a feeling that making a new PR even though I don't see the changes in there, might do it. since the commit is already in Github's master but just not merger in the code until I re-create a new PR using the same XYZ branch. but I'm not confident.